# How can i manage my odoo products?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, data-warehouse

I'm having this issue with odoo and i don't know how to manage it.
Actually i'm having a product called SIMCARD and each sim card has a number and can be activated or not.
My problem is that where can i add those two property in my product and then.I want when i make stock moves trace each single simcar. Actually,when i go to inventory and Request Procurement.i will be only to demand a quantity of sim cards but then if i want to see each simcard alone.I can't.I want to see each sim card i made Procurement and can change those 2 property and also is it possible to have a serial number or bar code for each simcard?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use serial number for your product sim card

Comment: yes i found that but how can i do that for each simcard ? when i make approvisionning it will tell me the quantity but later on i want for each one and then i want the two fields simcard number and status(activated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem can be solved by the following way.

> First, you need to add the field in your **sales order line & stock move**. **For example** sim card number and status(activated).

**then**

> at the time when your stock move generate take the **reference of sales
>   order line from the Procurement**.